# Why do Star Trek ships have weapons when there are better means to destroy enemy ships?

Tags: star-trek, technology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't transporter technology be used as a weapon?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13539/why-cant-transporter-technology-be-used-as-a-weapon)

Why does the transporter technology not make "conventional" weapons (beam weapons and missiles) completely obsolete? 
You could use the transporter to teleport a bomb inside of an enemy ship. In the case they have some kind of protection, teleport it outside of the ship and detonate it there, it's still more effective than having it fly all the way there. The same with beam weapons: use the transporter technology to constantly teleport them around, instead of having them on board all at the same place? (Just as transporter technology would make a modern carrier battle group obsolete as you could teleport dozens of small PT boats in and out)

Does the transporter technology have some limitation which limits its use as described above?

Comment: This question is addressed: Why can't transporter technology be used as a weapon - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/13539/2765

Comment: Remember, transporter can't penetrate shields. It includes own shields, too (so you can't beam weapons randomly without harming yourself).

Comment: It doesn't include your own shields. Star Trek consistently shows human beings beaming out through their own shields, and even uses it as a throwaway plot point when they need to get through someone else's shields. TNG shows them finding the "hole" in someone else's shields and using them to beam through.

Comment: @JohnO: No, not "consistently" at all. On multiple occasions away teams have had to wait because the ship has come under attack and the shields have been raised.